# Finding the smallest $k$ so that specific items are spaced exactly three apart

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

An inventory consists of an ordered list of $k$ items that are marked as "available" and $5$ items that are marked as "unavailable". What is the smallest value of $k$ such that we are certain that at least two items that are marked as available will be exactly three items apart in this list? Justify your answer. (Three apart means $A_i**A_j$ where each $*$ could be either $A$ or $U$).

I know this has to do with permutations and combinations but I've always been bad at them. I thought that the question would dumb down to identifying the extreme case and adding "$A$s" till the condition above has been satisfied but that seems quite wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to look at every third item on the list. This splits the list into three sets: those at locations $1,4,7,10,...$, those at $2,5,8,11,...$, and those at $3,6,9,12,...$.

If you have only 5 unavailable items, one of these sets must have at most one unavailable item in it, by the pigeonhole principle. What does that mean for the size of that set if there are no two available items three-apart? What does that mean for the size of the other sets? And for the size of the list?

Once you have worked through those questions, you should be able to find an example of a longest possible list without a pair of three-apart available items, and then formulate a proof of why a list that is one item longer must contain such a pair.

Comment: I thought it might be the pigeonhole principle but couldn't figure out how it actually applied. So going forward, would k = 9 then?

Comment: @TRONIIX Only one of the sets is limited to size 3, but it could be the third set, i.e. $\{3,6,9\}$.

Comment: I figured. However, I found that the longest list without a pair of three-apart available items is A1, U1, A2, U2, A3, U3, A4, U4, A5, U5, A6. Is that correct? Does that mean the largest list must be 14? And therefore, the largest k=9?

Comment: @TRONIIX That list of $k=11$ items is one example of a maximal list without a 3-apart available pair (there are 3 others of the same length you might want to find). So a list of $k=12$ items or more is guaranteed to have a pair of 3-apart available items. Prove it.

Comment: Are you sure? I retried and I'm getting a list of 13 items in one way and 14 items in another: 1) A1, U1, A2, U2, A3, U3, A4, U4, A5, U5, A6, A7, A8, A9 (k=9, total = 14). 2) A8, A1, U1, A2, U2, A3, U3, A4, U4, A5, U5, A6, A7 (k=8, total = 13)

Comment: @TRONIIX The first has A6-A9, and the second has A8-A2 and A5-A7.

Comment: Yeah so that there are at least two 3-apart available items... Is that not what they mean?

Comment: @TRONIIX They are asking for the *shortest* that guarantees such a pair. Of course a list of, say, $k=100$ will have such a pair. My answer looks for the longest without such a pair, so that taking a list with one more item than that is the shortest to guarantee such a pair.

Comment: But how does a list of 12 items achieve this? Can you give an example of such an order so that at least 2 pairs are three-apart?

Comment: @TRONIIX Why are you asking about 2 pairs? The question is about the shortest list to guarantee one pair.

Comment: Nevermind. I see where I got it wrong. I was thinking that the question was asking about 2 pairs but it says "two items". I finally get it :) Thank you so much!